# Self-referential generic class templates

Tags: c#, generics

Is it possible to build the following heterogeneous (generic) linked list data type?

```
 class MyClass<TPrev, TNext> 
      where TNext : MyClass<TPrev2, TNext2> 
           where TPrev2 : MyClass<TPrev, TNext>
```

edit: Notice in particular the new type TNext2 which is not defined.

edit2: ... which makes the above snippet non-functional as written.

Comment: Have you tried? What happened when you did?

Comment: See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx

Comment: @Henk - I did think it curious that this question came up today, following that blog post :)

Comment: @John Saunders: TNext2 is not a top-level type parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't model what you want. You could do this:

```
class Link<TPrev, TValue, TNext>
{
    public TPrev  Prev { get; set; }
    public TValue Value { get; set; }
    public TNext  Next { get; set; }
}
```

But you can't do:

```
class Link<???, TValue, ???>
{
    public Link<???> Prev { get; set; }
    public TValue Value { get; set; }
    public Link<???> Next { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that if you declare that the previous and next elements of your list must also be lists of some generic type, then you've attempted to define a type of infinite size. There's no way to say, "There is no next node after this" because the next node must be a `Link<T>` for some *other* link type and you run into an infinite regress.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible because you haven't defined `TNext2` or `TPrev2` as part of the class definition. You can't have a generic parameter like that unless its an existing type, or is a generic type parameter in the class definition.

But then, if `TPrev2` is an existing type, you can't specify a constraint on it like you are trying to do.

Comment: Obviously what I wrote, as is, doesn't work: If it did I would not have posed the question. The issue is where it is possible to get equivalent functional behavior somehow.

Comment: That is not clear from your question. You state: "Is it possible to build the following heterogeneous (generic) linked list data type?"

Comment: So what is it exactly that you are trying to model? Maybe if you can elaborate in English, we can help you translate it to C#.

Comment: A bi-directional linked list of heterogeneous objects. Each object can point to another object of a different type with type information maintained between adjacent nodes: TNext.TPrev should know the type of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2008/06/12/generics-the-knee-bone-s-connected-to-the-toe-bone-pattern.aspx) for an interesting idea on the topic. In essence you could do something like this:

```
public abstract class LinkedListBase<T>
    where T : LinkedListBase<T>
{
    public T Next { get; set; }
    public T Previous { get; set; }
}
public class LinkedListImpl : LinkedListBase<LinkedListImpl>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // all of the value properties go here...
}
```

So essentially the value itself contains the links to the previous and next.